# Cobertura maven plugin incorrect version

Tags: maven, cobertura

I am using cobertura and when I specify version 2.5 it downloads 1.9. Why?

My pom:
        
        
            
                
                    org.codehaus.mojo
                    cobertura-maven-plugin
                    2.5.2
                    
                        
                            
                                za/co/c2d/**/*.class
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            clean
                            pre-site
                            
                                clean
                            
                        
                        
                            instrument
                            site
                            
                                instrument
                                cobertura

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- use mvn cobertura:cobertura to generate cobertura reports -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>html</format>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Output:
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.2:instrument (default-cli) @ services ---
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/cobertura/cobertura/1.9.4.1/cobertura-1.9.4.1.pom

When I run this it then breaks with 
[ERROR] net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.ParseException: Encountered " ">" "> ""

As I understand it, this was fixed in version 2.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can't you can't specify version inside brackets ... could you explain more about project hierarchy ? and your full pom.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are specifying the version of the **cobertura-maven-plugin** , which is a different jar from **cobertura** package

The plugin 2.5.2 uses internally cobertura version 1.9.4.1 as stated in http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/